# Hierarchical clustering with coordinates and non-spatial parameters

Tags: r, spatial, hierarchical-clustering

Say I have this data set containing the centroid of each village (x_cent, y_cent), as well as a few non-spatial parameters like total population and number of primary schools, paved roads, and village size.

```
set.seed(1234)

dat <-
  expand.grid(
    district         = c(1:2),
    sub_district     = c(1:7),
    sub_sub_district = c(1:19), 
    village_id       = c(1:2) 
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(district, sub_district, sub_sub_district, village_id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    # Total population
    tot_pop = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 100, sd = 5000),
    # Number of primary schools
    p_schl = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 2, sd = 6),
    # Paved road
    p_road = sample(0:1, size = dplyr::row_number(), replace = FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(district, sub_district, sub_sub_district, village_id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    # Size of village in hectares
    town_hec = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 300, sd = 320)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(district, sub_district, sub_sub_district, village_id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    # Coordinates
    x_cent = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 99.9, sd = 0.66), 
    y_cent = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 33.3, sd = 0.33)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

I want to generate clusters of villages based on spatial proximity as well as these non-spatial parameters (tot_pop, p_schl, p_road, and town_hec). I also want to weight the algorithm such that spatial proximity is more important than matching on the other covariates. Lastly, I want to be able to constrain the number of observations for each cluster.

I assume that this would be a hierarchical clustering model, but I am not sure how to implement this in R, and whether clustering on spatial and non-spatial covariates is possible.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution, marking as the answer for now:

First, rescale the variables that you want to include in your distance matrix. In this case I assign a larger weight (10) to the coordinate variables (x_cent and y_cent).

```
dat$x_cent <- scales::rescale(dat$x_cent, to = c(0, 10))
dat$y_cent <- scales::rescale(dat$y_cent, to = c(0, 10))
dat$tot_pop <- scales::rescale(dat$tot_pop, to = c(0, 1))
```

Second, subset the data to include only the covariates with which you are calculating distance:

```
dat <- dat[, c("x_cent", "y_cent", "tot_pop")]
```

Next, calculate the distance matrix:

```
dist <- distances::distances(as.data.frame(dat))
```

Calculate clusters using the `scclust` package and append values to the original dataset. This package allows you to incorporate constraints on your cluster size.

```
clust <- scclust::hierarchical_clustering(distances = dist, size_constraint = 10)
final <- dplyr::bind_cols(dat, clust) %>% dplyr::rename(block = `...4`)
```

You can see how many observations exist per cluster:

```
investigate_cluster <- dplyr::group_by(final, block) %>% dplyr::summarise(count = length(block))

head(investigate_cluster)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  block     count
  <scclust> <int>
1 0            10
2 1            10
3 2            10
4 3            10
5 4            10
6 5            10
```

And easily visualize your clusters:

```
ggplot(final, mapping = aes(x = x_cent, y = y_cent, color = factor(block))) +
  geom_point() +
  ggConvexHull::geom_convexhull(alpha = .5, aes(fill = factor(block))) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the hierarchical clustering method depends on a distance matrix, an easy way to put more weight on some variable would be to scale those variables according to the importance you want them to have before computing the distance matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Wawvi -- how would you recommend implementing your suggestion in this context?

Comment: You could scale your non-spatial parameters to [0 ; 1] and your x and y coords to [0 ; 4] if you want spatial parameters to weight 4 time more than you non-spatial parameters. Then compute the distance matrix on those rescaled variables with the dist() function that you can then pass to hclust().

Comment: I see -- thanks for clarifying. I'm going to add possible solution using the scclust package in the answers section.